# Open a Web Page at User's First Login

Tags: unity, login, skel

I'd like to add a file that opens Google Chrome on a specific Web page the first time a user logs in to an Ubuntu box.

I am guessing it should go in the `/etc/skel` directory.

I don't know how to make it run only once, similar to the HUD Help that shows up right after the first login in Unity.

Answer (score 1):

create /etc/skel/.config/autostart/autostart-once.desktop which will execute
/usr/share/runonce.sh ...the last command of runonce.sh needs to delete autostart-once.desktop

I've tested this in Xubuntu 19.10, but it should work for other desktop environments, or you may need to change some details to your situation, but the idea works.